# "Definition of service not found" error when using pg_service.conf file with Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, database-connection

I'm trying to use a pg_service.conf file to manage database connections in my Django application, but I'm running into an error when trying to connect to the database using the named service.

Here's what my DATABASES setting in Django looks like:

```
python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'service': 'my_service'
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what my pg_service.conf file looks like (located at /etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf):

```
ini
[my_service]
host=localhost
port=5432
user=my_user
password=my_password
dbname=my_database
```

However, when I try to run my Django application, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: service file "/etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf" not found 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: definition of service "my_service" not found
```

I've checked that the pg_service.conf file exists in the correct location and has the correct permissions, and I've also verified that the service name in my DATABASES setting matches the service name in pg_service.conf. What else could be causing this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I've tried:

- Verified that the `pg_service.conf` file exists in `/etc/postgresql-common/` and has the correct permissions (owned by `postgres` user with `0640` permissions).
- Verified that the service name in my `DATABASES` setting matches the service name in `pg_service.conf`.
- Restarted my Django application after making changes to `pg_service.conf`.
- Confirmed that I can connect to the database using the same connection parameters in a regular PostgreSQL connection string (without using `pg_service.conf`).
- Restarted the PostgreSQL service using systemctl restart postgresql.

What I was expecting:

- To be able to connect to my PostgreSQL database using the named service `my_service` defined in `pg_service.conf` from my Django application.
- To not receive the "definition of service not found" error when running my Django application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to file permissions for the `pg_service.conf` file. I updated the file permissions by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod 0640 /etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf
```

This sets the file permissions to be owned by the `postgres` user and to have `0640` permissions.

For more information about managing file permissions in Linux, you can refer to the following resources:

- chmod command in Linux: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chmod-command-linux/ ↗
- Understanding Linux File Permissions: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/ ↗"